# A bridge between an SSH and an S3 bucket for file transfers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, synchronization

I have 17 gigs of images directly on my server that I would like to move to S3. First I tried to scp them and it it took roughly 9 hours, so that doesn't seem to be a good idea to use those because other people have probably touched those images since then. I'm thinking something similar to rsync, but rsync wouldn't work because I can't install it on an S3 bucket..

Does anyone know a good way to sync images between a server host and an s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is [s3sync](http://www.s3sync.net/wiki) which is an S3 wrapper written in Ruby.

If you're really in a bind, you can always ship a hard drive to Amazon using their [import/export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) service.

Comment: Hmm..good advice. the s3sync does seem like a viable solution if it actually worked. Turns out, it doesn't. I spent 5 hours on it today messing around with the s3config.yml , literally anything/everything that could have potentially got it to work , and it didn't.